# Mobile Studio : Multiple From Names for the same long/short code within the Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilestudio

I know it is possible to assign different From Names for the same long/short code in different business units.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_setting_the_from_name_for_your_mobileconnect_account.htm&type=5

But, is it possible to set different From Names for the same long/short code with in the same business unit?

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the considerations of the help documentation about [From Names](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_setting_the_from_name_for_your_mobileconnect_account.htm&type=5) it is not possible to set up different From Names in the same BU OOTB (maybe if you contact directly with support they can enable it but I am not sure they could).

As a workaround, the From Name can be customized in the SMS configuration in a Journey so you can change it for each communication.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Marketing Cloud Support has suggested that we create an attribute(Eg: Named 'Sender')  under Audience Builder -> Contact Builder -> Mobile Connect Data.

And populate the attribute with the From Names(either list or data extension column mapping while importing data) you want. Use it while sending an outbound message for From Name as %%Sender%%.

Hope this helps.