# Custom From Name SMS in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

Good morning,

is it possible to customise the send name from Journey Builder as per below example so that it will render visually to the recipient upon message delivery and override the Account level one?

[Mobile Studio : Multiple From Names for the same long/short code within the Business Unit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265569/mobile-studio-multiple-from-names-for-the-same-long-short-code-within-the-busi)

Experiences with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to know is that you can try and experience it yourself. To me, I have no problems with using multiple From Names for the same short/long code in my MC account.

Additionally, you may want to consider about the country law where some countries may require the From Name registration while others do not.

Comment: Thanks for this.  To clarify, are you referring to the custom From Name assigned to the SMS send in a Journey related to a code?  We are waiting for the codes to be provisioned still so not able to test yet.  The target countries do not require From Name registration.